# How to creates a Counts[] function that includes zero?

Tags: list-manipulation, counting

In the following example, I'm trying to how many times each integer 1-n appears in list 'a'.  But if an element did not appear in a list, Counts[] creates an association that returns the element instead of zero.  So the result is a mixed list of counts and integers, with no indication of which you're looking at.

```
n = 10;
a = RandomInteger[n, n]
c = Counts[a];
Table[i /. c, {i, 1, n}]

{7, 7, 0, 7, 10, 5, 3, 0, 1, 8}
{1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 9, 1}
```

Is there a way to make a `Counts[]` function that can count zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Lookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup) instead of [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll):

```
n = 10;
SeedRandom[1]
a = RandomInteger[n,n];
c = Counts[a]

Table[i /. c, {i, 1, n}]
Lookup[c, Range[10], 0]
```

> <|1 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 0 -> 4, 7 -> 1, 8 -> 1, 6 -> 1|>
>
> {1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 9, 10}
>
> {1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}

Comment: Thanks this does just what I needed.  But I didn't understand your comment about ReplaceAll.  I didn't use ReplaceAll.  Is that function inside something I used?

Comment: @JerryGuern Jerry, `i /. c` is short hand for `ReplaceAll[i, c]`

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `SparseArray` with additive matrix assembly which may be a bit faster:

```
n = 1000000;
a = RandomInteger[n, n];
counts = Lookup[Counts[a], Range[1, n], 0]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

counts2 = Rest@With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]},
     Internal`WithLocalSettings[
      SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}],

      SparseArray[Partition[a+1, 1] -> 1, {n+1}],

      SetSystemOptions[spopt]]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.30965
>
> 0.148508
>
> True

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {7, 7, 0, 7, 10, 5, 3, 0, 1, 8};
Counts[a] /@ Range[10] /. Missing -> (0 &)
```

> {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1}

Alternatively,

```
Block[{Missing = (0 &)}, Counts[a] /@ Range[10]]
```

> {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1}